# Web browse a list of links

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to browse a list of links with R, but I get an error. Here is my code

```
link <- character() 

for (i in 0:9) {
  link <- c(link,paste('https://nex-gddp-cmip6.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/NEX-GDDP-CMIP6/ACCESS-CM2/historical/r1i1p1f1/pr/pr_day_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_200',i,'.nc', sep = ""))
  print(link)
}

browseURL(link)
```

This is the result

```
Error in browseURL(link) : 'url' must be a non-empty character string
```

I would thank your help

Comment: The error message is odd, but I believe `browseURL()` only works if you try one link at a time. Try `browseURL(link[1])`

Comment: Thanks for your response. How could I make it work for the entire list?

Comment: you can do `purrr::walk(link, browseURL)`

Answer (score 2):

Remove `c(link,)` from the loop and put `browseURL(link)` inside

```
for (i in 0:9) {
  link <- paste('https://nex-gddp-cmip6.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/NEX-GDDP-CMIP6/ACCESS-CM2/historical/r1i1p1f1/pr/pr_day_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_200',i,'.nc', sep = "")
  browseURL(link)
}
```

You can also use `lapply`:

```
lapply(0:9, function(i) {
  link <- paste('https://nex-gddp-cmip6.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/NEX-GDDP-CMIP6/ACCESS-CM2/historical/r1i1p1f1/pr/pr_day_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_200',i,'.nc', sep = "")
  browseURL(link)
})
```